# Football Goal Records

Tags: football, records, trivia

What is the world record for:

- Most goals scored by one team in a game?
- Most combined goals in a game?
- Most goals scored by a team in a season?

Comment: Australia defeated American Samoa 31-0. This is the record for most goals in a game in an international. http://www.fifa.com/worldcup/archive/edition=4395/preliminaries/preliminary=3863/matches/match=22243/report.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer to both of your first question is Australia 31–0 win over American Samoa - You can read about it on [Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Australia_31%E2%80%930_American_Samoa) and even see highlits of the game over [youtube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ahf3eHikZs8)

There is some confusion about the score at the end of the match since the score board shows 32-0 but:

> At the end of the match, the scoreboard at the stadium showed a 32–0. 
>   Only after the statistician did a recount, the 31–0 scoreline was
>   announced,   After the match, FIFA went on to release the official
>   statistics after receiving the official report from the referee and
>   match officials, which confirm the 31–0 scoreline.

As for your third question, it is very hard to answer it because it can include trophies? can it include friendly games?  can it be at any league level(for example english fourth division)?

the most league goals scored in a season I found was **134** by Peterborough United at english Fourth Division, 1960–61 season. ([Source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Football_records_in_England#Goals))